# Doctrine: 1 to many relationship with multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, schema.yml

I am using **Doctrine 1.2** and looking for the correct syntax
for creating a **1:n relationship** between two tables in my **schema.yml**

Usual this is done by:

```
BookChapter:
  columns:
    ...
  relations:
    Book:
      class: Book
      local: book_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
```

However in my special case there are **2 foreign primary keys**.

```
BookReader

book:
  type: integer(8)
  primary: true
reader: 
  type: integer(8)
  primary: true


BookReaderDetails

book_id: integer(8)
reader_id: integer(8)
...
```

Is it possible to define such a relation with a doctrine schema file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine doesn't play nicely with multiple primary keys unless they are being used as a many-to-many reference table (junction table).

If you want a 1-to-many relation and not many-to-many, you're probably best off adding a primary key column to `BookReader`. You can then put a unique index on book and reader.

Comment: I have to admit that my example is a bad one. Despite the fact that it does not make much sense there my intention is to create a one to many relationship between a junction table and another table.